# Subquery returns more than 1 row when join

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, hibernate

class structure inheritancetype.joined jpa
I want to join different table on case.

[blind DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiz0i.png)

```
╔════╦══════════════╦════════════╦
║ id ║ account_id   ║ type       ║ 
╠════╬══════════════╬════════════╬
║  1 ║ 1            ║  POST      ║
║  2 ║ 2            ║  COMMENT   ║
║  3 ║ 1            ║  POST      ║
║  4 ║ 2            ║  POST      ║
║  5 ║ 2            ║  BOARD     ║
╚════╩══════════════╩════════════╩
```

[post_blind DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PfXh.png)

```
╔════╦══════════════╦
║ id ║ post_id      ║
╠════╬══════════════╬
║  1 ║ 1            ║
║  3 ║ 3            ║
║  4 ║ 2            ║
╚════╩══════════════╩
```

[post DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YqRj.png)

```
╔════╦══════════════╦════════════╦
║ id ║ is_blind     ║ account_id ║
╠════╬══════════════╬════════════╬
║  1 ║ 1            ║  1         ║
║  2 ║ 0            ║  1         ║
║  3 ║ 0            ║  2         ║
╚════╩══════════════╩════════════╩
```

Blind has two status. `blind` and `blind waiting`
When post or comment blinded, blind object created and after 6 hours later, post is_blind or comment is_blind column turns true so users can't watch that content.

when type is 'POST'
: blind ->  post_blind -> post
and select blind that `post` is_blind column is false and `blind` account_id = :account_id

```
SELECT *
FROM blind b
         LEFT JOIN post_blind pb ON b.id = pb.id
         LEFT JOIN comment_blind cb ON b.id = cb.id
WHERE b.account_id = 2
          and (b.type = 'POST' AND (select is_blind
                                    from post p
                                    right join post_blind pb on p.id = pb.post_id) is true)
   OR (b.type = 'COMMENT' AND (select is_blind
                               from comment c
                                right join comment_blind cb on c.id = cb.comment_id) is true);
```

It works if account has one blind post and one blind comment.
However, if the account has more than one blind post, `Subquery will return more than one row` return.

I have already looked at other question and answer but still don't understand.
anyone can help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

use **EXISTS** keyword

```
SELECT *
FROM blind b
LEFT JOIN post_blind pb ON b.id = pb.id
LEFT JOIN comment_blind cb ON b.id = cb.id
WHERE b.account_id = 2
     and (b.type = 'POST' and EXISTS
        (select is_blind
        from post p
        right join post_blind pb on p.id = pb.post_id) is true)
            OR (b.type = 'COMMENT' 
                and EXISTS (select is_blind
                            from comment c
                            right join comment_blind cb on c.id = cb.comment_id)
                );
```

Comment: Thanks. It solve `Subquery returns more than 1 row` but the result includes the post is_blind column being false.